# Jmeter-How to share users of one Thread to different Threads in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

```
                               Login Thread (users 15)
                                       |
               ----------------------------------------------------
               |                       |                          |
           Order Thread           Search Thread            Logout Thread
          5 user out of 15      5 user out of 15         5 user out of 15 

  I want to bypass login users of my very first thread to different thread.
```

How can i achieve this pls help.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhVvg.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [Throughput Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) is what you are looking for, in this case you can use the same [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) (passing user session between different thread groups is possible but not recommended as it violates JMeter design and best practices)

Example [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) would be something like:

- Thread Group (threads: 15)

  - Login Sampler
  - Search Throughput Controller (percent executions, 33.3)

    - Search Sampler
  - Order Throughput Controller (percent executions, 33.3)

    - Order Sampler
  - Logout Throughput Controller (percent executions, 33.3)

    - Logout Sampler

[image: JMeter Throughput Controller]

This way `Login Sampler` will be executed 15 times and the others will be executed 5 times each. If you increase the number of threads the distribution will remain.

[image: JMeter Throughput Controller effect]

See [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more information regarding Throughput Controller and the other ways of the load distribution in JMeter tests.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want you can keep 3 separate Thread Groups and reference "Login" sampler in each thread group using [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller)

Comment: Please help, all 5 users are same for all sample. mean same user is searching, ordering, and logout. it is 33.3 but same users.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [Interleave Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller) after your login request as a parent of all other requests so the structure would be like this:

```
                       Login Thread (users 15)
                                      |
           ----------------------------------------------------
                                      |                         
                             interleave controller
           ----------------------------------------------------
           |                          |                       |
       Order Thread           Search Thread            Logout Thread
      5 user out of 15      5 user out of 15         5 user out of 15
```

Make sure the option **interleave across threads** is on. Now each thread will do one of the three request only and then leave so the scenario would be like this:

- First thread will login then order.
- Second thread will login and search.
- Third thread will login and logout.
- Fourth thread will login and order.

and so on, so at the end 5 users will only order, other 5 will search and the last 5 will logout.